# Change canvas color pyqt5 qml

Tags: python, canvas, pyqt, qml, pyqt5

I writing the simple pyqt5+qml application that will draw a function plot. I'm trying to change the background color of the canvas on click of the button, but nothing happens, here is the code.

### main.py

```
from PyQt5.QtGui import QGuiApplication
from PyQt5.QtQml import QQmlApplicationEngine
from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject, pyqtSignal, pyqtSlot


class Plot(QObject):
    def __init__(self):
        QObject.__init__(self)

    updCanv = pyqtSignal(arguments=['upd'])


    @pyqtSlot()
    def upd(self):
        self.updCanv.emit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
import sys

# Create an instance of the application
sys.argv += ['--style', 'material']
app = QGuiApplication(sys.argv)
# Create QML engine
engine = QQmlApplicationEngine()
# Create a plot object
plot = Plot()
# And register it in the context of QML
engine.rootContext().setContextProperty("plot", plot)
# Load the qml file into the engine
engine.load("main.qml")

engine.quit.connect(app.quit)
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

### main.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 2.1
import QtQuick.Controls.Material 2.1
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.2

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 240
    title: qsTr("Function plot")
    Material.theme: Material.Dark

    GridLayout {
        anchors.top: parent.top
        anchors.left: parent.left
        anchors.right: parent.right
        anchors.margins: 9

        columns: 4
        rows: 4
        rowSpacing: 10
        columnSpacing: 10

        Text {
            color: "whitesmoke"
            text: qsTr("Left bound")
        }

        TextField {
            id: left_bound
        }

        Text {
            color: "whitesmoke"
            text: qsTr("Right bound")
        }

        TextField {
            id: right_bound
        }

        ComboBox{
                model: ['cos', 'sin', 'x^2']
        }

        Button {
            height: 40
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            text: qsTr("Build plot")


            onClicked: {
                plot.upd(left_bound.text, right_bound.text)
            }
        }

        Canvas {
            id: canv
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            height: 500
            Layout.columnSpan: 4
            onPaint: {
                var ctx = getContext("2d");
                ctx.fillStyle = Qt.rgba(1, 1, 1, 1);
                ctx.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
            }

        }
    }

    Connections {
        target: plot

        onUpdCanv: {
            onPaint: {
                var ct = canv.getContext("2d");
                ct.fillStyle = Qt.rgba(0, 0, 1, 1);
                ct.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
                canv.requestPaint();
        }

    }
}
}
```

What can I do with it? How can I update the canvas when I want to change plot or choose another function to show, also I'll need to add function to zoom/out the plot, Is it possible to make with Canvas object?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not understand the use of the Plot class, it seems unnecessary because the only thing you do is to forward the signal it receives. If you want to change the color you can do it directly using only `QML`, in the following example random colors are generated each time the button is pressed.

**main.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 2.1
import QtQuick.Controls.Material 2.1
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.2

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 240
    title: qsTr("Function plot")
    Material.theme: Material.Dark

    property color plotColor : "blue"
    onPlotColorChanged: canv.requestPaint()

    GridLayout {
        anchors.top: parent.top
        anchors.left: parent.left
        anchors.right: parent.right
        anchors.margins: 9

        columns: 4
        rows: 4
        rowSpacing: 10
        columnSpacing: 10

        Text {
            color: "whitesmoke"
            text: qsTr("Left bound")
        }

        TextField {
            id: left_bound
        }

        Text {
            color: "whitesmoke"
            text: qsTr("Right bound")
        }

        TextField {
            id: right_bound
        }

        ComboBox{
            model: ['cos', 'sin', 'x^2']
        }

        Button {
            height: 40
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            text: qsTr("Build plot")
            onClicked: plotColor = Qt.rgba(Math.random(),Math.random(),Math.random(),1);
        }


        Canvas {
            id: canv
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            height: 500
            Layout.columnSpan: 4
            onPaint: {
                var ctx = getContext("2d");
                ctx.fillStyle = plotColor;
                ctx.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

If you want to zoomIn/zoomOut you can use the [scale function](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_scale.asp), so you could also implement the layout of various graphics.

On the other hand I think that the simplest thing is to use the module [QtCharts](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtcharts-index.html), you have already implemented all that kind of tasks.

If it is not necessary you do not create classes on the python/C++ side, that is, if you can do everything in `QML` it is much simpler, so I indicate that I do not see the need for the Plot class.

If you see that Qt Charts is not enough, or you do not want to use canvas and you feel more familiar with python you could create your own canvas using the [`QQuickPaintedItem`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qquickpainteditem.html) class.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it works.
It's a class task, I need that class because later I will generate the points on the python side when I click the "Build plot" button.
Unfortunately, I didn't asked a right question.
Better question is, can I fill the Canvas with white background, and when I click the button, it will draw for example a point on this white Canvas? Sorry for multiple questions.

Comment: @karambaq 
In SO, a question is asked per post, that is why it says ask question, it does not say ask questions, I invite you to create a question indicating what you want, I would also recommend you to investigate a little, a good reference is https://qmlbook.github.io/ch07/index.html